# Date format when written in Excel comes as general not date

Tags: r

I am using openxlsx package to write back a file. I have already used as.date and format function to make my fates look like `dd-mmm-yyyy`.

However, when I open the Excel file, even though the date comes as, say "12-may-2018", I cannot filter them out like Excel dates. It shows that the type of the data is general.

Even if I convert it to date format in Excel, it still doesn't let me filter it out by year, month, and day, which happens for Excel dates. I can convert them to date type by manually placing my cursor in the middle of a cell and pressing the return key.

Doing that for the whole data will be too much manual effort which I want to reduce. Is there any way to make it happen. Thanks for any suggestions that you guys give.

Here is my code:

```
 data$datecolumns <- as.date(as.numeric(data$datecolumn), origin = origin - somenumberforcalibartion, format = "%d")
data$datecolumn <- format(data$datecolumn, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
write.xlsx(data, filename)
```

Here, datecolumn is being read in Excel numeric format.

I just saw a code snippet where the date was being read from CSV as string converted to POSIXct and then again written as CSV is being read as date in Excel. Haven't found anything for Xlsx yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and *not* the reason why I downvoted, but simply wondering - why would you want to transfer your data back to excel???

Comment: Please provide a small example of your data and code. At least people who own an Excel might be able to give you a hand.

Comment: i cannot ptovide data or code as it is for a work project. and to bring it back to excel, so that I can plug it back into a BI tool.

Answer (score 0):

Format function makes the date back to string. Which was causing the whole issue, hence remove format function and things work fine. @Tjebo @Roman Lustrik helped me for this.